# How would I access the Bootstrap v5 color palette via CDN

Tags: wordpress, twig, bootstrap-5

So I (an amateur) am only using the CDN for Bootstrap v5 in my custom theme and would also like those other colors (other than then the themes of primary, secondary, etc) in my Twig files that they reference [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/color/#all-colors), But I have not found out how to do it properly.

`<div class="bg--bs-blue">`  and  `<div class="font--bs-blue">`  are not working, its says something about using root but wasn't sure what that means?

I really don't want to import the whole Botstrap css file, I really would like to continue only using the CDN if at all possible - I see those colors and fonts when I "inspect" my source files so I assume they are usable somehow?

```
:root {
    --bs-blue: #0d6efd;
    --bs-indigo: #6610f2;
    --bs-purple: #6f42c1;
    --bs-pink: #d63384;
    --bs-red: #dc3545;
    --bs-orange: #fd7e14;
    --bs-yellow: #ffc107;
    --bs-green: #198754;
    --bs-teal: #20c997;
    --bs-cyan: #0dcaf0;
    --bs-white: #fff;
    --bs-gray: #6c757d;
    --bs-gray-dark: #343a40;
    --bs-primary: #0d6efd;
    --bs-secondary: #6c757d;
    --bs-success: #198754;
    --bs-info: #0dcaf0;
    --bs-warning: #ffc107;
    --bs-danger: #dc3545;
    --bs-light: #f8f9fa;
    --bs-dark: #212529;
    --bs-font-sans-serif: system-ui,-apple-system,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans","Liberation Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
    --bs-font-monospace: SFMono-Regular,Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,"Liberation Mono","Courier New",monospace;
    --bs-gradient: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}
```

~ Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are [CSS variables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/css-variables/). You can't use them directly from CDN, but you can create new classes that reference them...

```
.text-indigo {
    color: var(--bs-indigo);
}
```

```
<div class="text-indigo">This is indigo color text</div>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/HCLEjyyKpy)

Comment: Thanks for your help ... could you also tell me how to use the indigo-100, indigo-200, etc ?

Comment: Those are only available through SASS https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/color/#all-colors

Comment: Is there a css trick to reference the whole list like with a wildcard, so I wouldn't have to retype for every color `.text-* {
    color: var(--bs-indigo);
}`

Comment: Sorry no this is really how/why SASS is used. Please mark the answer accepted since it answer your original question.

Comment: Would someone please explain why wouldn't doesn't work for me: `.text--blue, .bkgd--blue {
  color: var(--bs-blue);
}` The text--blue works fine but the bkgd--blue does not work?

Comment: Assuming `.bkgd--blue` refers to background ... CSS `color` is not `background-color` they're different properties

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234792/discussion-between-shrockco-and-zim).

Comment: Ask a different question